# Litespeedcache key domain registration error

Tags: plugins, errors

I used for some time the Litespeedcache plugin with WordPress, but now I found a problem with the key domain registration. Seems that something are injecting code into the REST API where it should not do this, in technical support words.

My server technical support says this:

They sayed:

Your domain ‘fotov60.com’ seems to not be responding properly in the URL indicated in the screenshot.

When I access https://www.fotov60.com/wp-json/litespeed/v1/token, it shows the following:

`{"_res":"ok"}`
This is not a valid JSON response; it should be like the last part:

`{“_res”:“ok”}`

I would recommend starting your investigations from there.

Someone have idea what are happenning and how to fix it? My web is https://www.fotov60.com

[image: key domain registration error]

Comment: You'll just need to do the standard debugging steps: disable all plugins and switch themes until the issue is resolved so that you can narrow down what's responsible. Other than that please keep in mind that third party plugins are off topic, and this site is geared towards development questions, not support. If you need support with the plugin I suggest asking the plugin developer or using its support forum.